# Test which Numpy function argument has more than one element

Tags: python, numpy, arguments

Consider the following function:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    """ Toy function

    """
    return a, b, c
```

Each of these arguments will be of type `numpy.array`. I need to efficiently determine which of these arguments has more than one element for use further in the function. I'd like to avoid testing each argument with an `if` statement as the list can be large and performance is important.  Assume that only one argument will have more than one element.

How can I determine which of the input arguments has more than one element?

Comment: Can you change how your function is called? If so, you can probably get what you need with kwargs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs

Comment: What's the problem with using e.g. `numpy.array.size`? It shouldn't take longer than 1 ms on the slowest cpus and is mostly independent of array size.

Comment: I'd like to avoid writing a bunch of `if` statements to test each of the args.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `locals()` to get a `dict` of all the arguments, then use `size` and `argmax` to find which is largest, like so:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([1,])
b=np.array([1,])
c=np.array([1,2,3])

def foo(a,b,c):
    args=locals()
    return args.items()[np.array([i[1].size for i in args.items()]).argmax()][1]

biggest = foo(a,b,c)
print biggest
# [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Or pass the values as `def foo(*args)` and test `args` with that comprehension.